# Determining whether a quadratic has a maximum or minimum

Tags: quadratics

So I've learnt that quadratics equations with a positive coefficient on the squared term have a minimum and a maximum if the coefficient is negative. But if we rearrange the quadratic and change the signs of the squared term, doesn't that mean the equation's maximum would change to a minimum and vice versa? e.g $ x^2 + 5x + 10 = 0$ becomes $-x^2 - 5x - 10 =0 $ even though we've not changed the equation, it's now got a maximum rather than a minimum. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You're perfectly right. The equation doesn't change, but the *in*equation is reversed.

Comment: It's functions that have minimums and maximums. Not equations.

Comment: You haven't (really) changed the equation, but you have changed the quadratic.  The question of a maximum or minimum refers to something like $x^2+5x+10$, **not** something like $x^2+5x+10=0$.

Comment: The $x$ values where $x^2+ax+b=0$ are the same as those where $-x^2-ax-b=0,$ but $x^2+ax+b$ differs from $-x^2-ax-b$ at other values of $x$

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=0$, the maximum and minimum of $f(x)$ are both $0$ (unless there are no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$).